# YamlLint validation

Tags: yaml, snakeyaml

I have a Yaml file like this

```
    name: hhh_aaa_bbb 
arguments:
    - !argument
        name: inputsss
        description: hhh aaa bbb
        required: true
    - !argument
        name: lll
        description: lll
        required: true
    - !argument
        name: ccc
        description: ccc
        required: true
source:
    !!com.abc.bbc.sss
        uri: !arg input
```

But when I use Yaml Lint to validate this yaml file in [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/),it removes all the "!" or "!!"  user arguments. Why does that happen?

This is the output i get from yaml lint after validation

```
    --- 
arguments: 
  - 
    description: "hhh aaa bbb"
    name: inputsss
    required: true
  - 
    description: lll
    name: lll
    required: true
  - 
    description: ccc
    name: ccc
    required: true
name: hhh_aaa_bbb
source: 
  uri: input
```

Comment: Your example is not a valid YAML file, your toplevel mapping starts with a 4 space indentation (before `name`) and on the second line you have zero indentation. If yamllint accepts that, you should keep far from using it.

Comment: Hey @Anthon All the Yaml Validators I have come across accepts this file. I mean all the three (YPaste, Online YAML Parser, NimYaml). Is there any other proper online resource dictates the right YAML format?

Comment: yamllint reduces your input to a single key-value pair, so does the Online YAML Parser. NimYaml accepts the data pasted in as if the first line is not indented, so that parser cannot be trusted. All three should give an error. You are much better off with a small python program trying to load the YAML, online parsers of data are a security hazard.

Comment: NimYAML also doesn't correctly handle octal numbers, but pretends to be YAML 1.2, keep away from that ...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *validate* a YAML file without having it transformed, use [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint/) (the linter, not the website -- yamllint.com is not a linter).

For your specific input, it would give:

```
$ yamllint file.yaml
file.yaml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
  1:18      error    trailing spaces  (trailing-spaces)
  4:9       error    wrong indentation: expected 6 but found 8  (indentation)
  8:9       error    wrong indentation: expected 6 but found 8  (indentation)
  12:9      error    wrong indentation: expected 6 but found 8  (indentation)
  17:9      error    wrong indentation: expected 4 but found 8  (indentation)
```

Answer (score 2):

YAMLLint is a website without imprint or any other information about author, purpose, and YAML implementation used. Without this information, you should be extremely careful to trust its output.

Only the author can tell you why they think it is a good idea to drop the tags. The resulting YAML is *not* equivalent to the input without the tags.

There are other sites you can use for online YAML validation:

- [YPaste](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/), the YAML reference parser (YAML 1.2)
- [Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), which uses PyYaml as backend (YAML 1.1)
- [NimYAML Testing Ground](http://flyx.github.io/NimYAML/testing.html), which uses NimYAML as backend (YAML 1.2)

(Full disclosure: I am the author of NimYAML)

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for this info. I have few more doubts. I want to convert A YAML with tags into a JSON file and a JSON to a YAML fiel with tags. Can you tell me what are tags like in a JSON construct?

Comment: Like for example, I used your NIMYAML to convert the same YAML file provided in the question to convert into a JSON. I got a JSON output which excluded the tags. I dont know how to add code to the comments. But you can try with my yaml. My requirement is to convert a JSON to YAML file which has tags. I use SnakeYAML as of now. And i use Javascript to convert the JSON to Yaml. but I dont get the tags. How to get these tags from JSON to YAML?

Comment: If you convert JSON to YAML, the only tags you can automatically generate are those from the [JSON Schema](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#schema/JSON/): `!!null`, `!!bool`, `!!int`, `!!float`, `!!map`, `!!seq` and `!!string`, corresponding to the JSON types (`!!int` and `!!float` both map to a JSON *number*). Paste JSON into the NimYAML online tool and look at the canonical output (this works because YAML is a superset of JSON). If you have a specific problem, please ask a new question.